# Add header and trailer record to output file after merging 1000s file into one

Tags: spring, spring-integration

i have Spring integration application which polls one directory for input files and write all those files to one common file. This works fine. Now, I have to add a header record and a trailer record to output file. I tried looking through SI but didn't get any way to insert header and trailer record at start and end of the output file using Spring Integration.

Does SI provide any such facility out of the box ? If some one have already implemented similar scenario. . . . Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what led you to think that such a custom logic must be included to `out of the box`, but your case is so specific that you should try to implement something yourself and not ask people to share their code. That is ignorantly.

Anyway let's take a look what we could do on the matter.

You may have some counter for files and where it is in the beginning you can send one more message (before sending the first file) to be stored in the target file as a header.

You can achieve it with the `<wire-tap>` which block the current thread for its `send` logic if everything is based on the `DirectChannel`.

Now it fully isn't clear (at least by your description) how you understand by your process that it is already the time to place the footer...

The `polling` process is infinite, and if files appear in the source directory all the time, there is no any hooks to determine the finish.

I may suggest to take a look into the [`AbstractMessageSourceAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#x4.2-conditional-pollers) and may be send the `trailer record` when we have a `null` result after `poll`. Like the logic in the `SimpleActiveIdleMessageSourceAdvice`:

```
public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
    if (result == null) {
        this.trigger.setPeriod(this.idlePollPeriod);
    }
    else {
        this.trigger.setPeriod(this.activePollPeriod);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Something like that.

Please, share more info about your use-case. When and how you would like to add that functionality, if my advices still aren't useful for you.